# QDockWidget behavior when changing its content

Tags: qt, resize, qdockwidget

I'm facing a problem with one of my `QDockWidget`. I have several `QWidget` items in a `QDockwidget` that are sometimes visible sometimes not.

I would like that my `QDockWidget` resizes itself depending on its content... Not only when `QWidgets` appear in it, but also when they disappear...

So far, my `QDockWidget` resizes itself when more `QWidgets` are displayed in it, but when I make them disappear, the `QDockWidget` stays at his previous size...

Any ideas to help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

There have been various posts over the years regarding control of the size of a `QDockWidget` in a `QMainWindow` dock area. I, too, have been struggling with this issue and have only been able to achieve a partial, and somewhat unsatisfactory, solution. The main problem (if you'll excuse the pun) is the inability to get a grip on the docking mechanism from the context of the `QMainWindow` that does the work of managing its dock areas. Attempts to use layout management - size policy and size hint controls - are not effective; the `QMainWindow` does its own thing when changing dock area sizes.

First, what limited success I have had:

Starting with a `QMainWindow` subclass (`MW`) and a `QDockWidget` subclass (`DW`). The `DW` has a `QWidget`, with a `QHBoxLayout`, that is `setWidget` in the `DW`. This layout has two widgets - I'll call them panels - with one of these panels intended to be shown or hidden depending on context: shown when the `DW` is in the bottom or top dock areas or floating, hidden otherwise. The `sizeHint` of the other panel after construction is used (along with appropriate margin spacing) to set the "base size" of the `DW`, with the constructed `sizeHint` width of the panel that will change visibility providing the increment to the base size when appropriate: the `DW` implementation is provided with a `panel_visible` method that is used to enable or disable the variable panel by applying setVisible to the panel and changing the value of the `sizeHint` by the increment value. The size policy of the `DW` and its panels are set to Minimum.

In the `MW` the `DW` `dockLocationChanged` and `topLevelChanged` signals are connected to a `DW_resize` slot. Here, when the `DW` `isVisible`, `isWindow` is false and `MW::dockWidgetArea` reports either `LeftDockWidgetArea` or `RightDockWidgeArea`, `DW::panel_visible(false)` is called to change the effective `DW` size (when the above conditions are not met `DW::panel_visible(true)` is called, of course). Invoking `DW::resize`, and `updateGeometry` and `update` in the `MW` has no effect on the dock area size. However if `DW::setMaximumSize(DW::sizeHint())` is called the dock area is correctly resized (no `updateGeometry` or `update` needed). This works as desired when the `DW` is floated (by dragging or double-clicking its title bar) and then redocked (by double-clicking its title bar or dragging it back over a side dock area). So far, so good.

Now the catch:

Having coerced the `MW` to fit its dock area to the prescribed `DW` size the `DW` needs to be released from its fixed size constraint so the user can resize the dock area by dragging the spit handle provided by the `MW` between to the dock area and the central area. The obvious answer is to just call `DW::setMaximumSize(0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF)` to "release" the `DW` constraints. Yes, except that update painting optimization that goes on behind the scenes coalesces the two sizing events with the result that the initial dock shrink action is lost. By putting a `qApp->sendPostedEvents()` and `qApp->flush()` between the two `setMaxmimumSize` calls this optimizing effect is avoided, the dock area is fit to the `DW` size and then left released so the dock area can be resized by the user ... sometimes.

This solution works when the `DW` goes from floating to docked by double-clicking the `DW` title bar, but not when the `DW` is dragged to a side dock in the `MW`. So, for example, if the user drags the `DW` from the left dock to the right dock the right dock area is not resized as expected; the receiving dock area remains the size of the floating `DW` that is produced during the drag from one side to another. If the `DW` in the receiving dock area has its title bar double-clicked (to become floating again) and then double-clicked again (to return it to the same dock area) the `MW` now fits the dock area as intended. On close inspection - by monitoring the `MW::paintEvent` - I see that when the dock area ends up the intended size the `flush()` is immediately followed by a `paintEvent` where the `DW` reports having the intended size and after the second `setMaximumSize` that unconstrains the `DW` a `paintEvent` occurs with the `DW` still the intended sized. But when the `DW` is dragged into the dock area the `flush()` is again immediately followed by `paintEvent` where the `DW` reports having the intended size, but after the second `setMaximumSize` in this case there are two `paintEvent`s with the `DW` now surprisingly having its previous floating size!

I have yet to find a way to prevent this unexplained overriding of the `DW` size after it has been correctly sized. It seems clear that an additional resize event is being generated by the `MW` after the `DW_resize` slot processing has returned, from size information that the `MW` has been holding from before the signals were emitted that lead to the slot. Monitoring the `MW::eventFilter` does indeed reveal a Resize event occurring after `DW_resize` has returned that changes the `DW` size from what it had been set to in the slot code back to its size when it was floating. When double-clicking the `DW` tile bar is used to move the `DW` from floating back into the side dock no additional Resize event occurs after the `DW_resize` slot returns.

The challenge, then, is how to prevent the unexpected resize reversion from happening after the `DW` has been correctly sized in the `DW_resize` slot. Perhaps some coercion in `DW::resizeEvent` will avoid this problem ....

Better, of course, would be if the Qt developers would provide the application developer thorough controls in the `QMainWindow` API over its dock management activities - especially dock area sizing - and/or access to the widgets that it uses for dock area management.

I am currently using Qt 4.6.2 on Linux, OS X and MS/Windows. The debug reports, above, were done on an Intel OS X 10.6.7 system; results differ somewhat on the different platforms, but the basic problem is the same. Perhaps these `QMainWindow`/`QDockWidget` issues have been dealt with in a later version of Qt? Perhaps someone has deeper insight into what is going on here and can offer a simple solution?

Comment: Qt 5.15.2, MacOs 12.6.1 Monterey still the same problem. Not encountered on Linux and Windows (probably, a closer exception would reveal anything, but it seems to be a Mac-specific problem)

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem. Inexplicably putting `restoreState()` twice has solved it for me.
 I'm using Qt 4.7.0.

```
void MainWnd::showEvent(QShowEvent *se){
QMainWindow::showEvent(se);

static bool first = true;

if (first){
   restoreState(...);
   restoreState(...);
   first = false;
}
}
```